# Help with solution for a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this differential equation:
$ \frac{d^2 \phi} { dx^2 }= k^2 \exp \left(\frac{\phi }{ E_t}\right) - \Omega $

In this case k and $\Omega$ are constants and $\phi$ is a function of x.

I tried to multiply both members by $\frac{d\phi}{dx} $ but it didn't bring me anywhere, I just obtained an integral which is not solvable.

Do you have suggestions to find a solution?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What is $E_t$? Your question is still unclear.

Comment: It's a parameter

Answer (score 0):

After you multiply by $\frac{d\phi}{dx}$ it should bring you somewhere. Hint:

$$\frac{d\phi}{dx}\frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}=[\frac{1}{2}(\frac{d\phi}{dx})^2]'$$

$$\frac{d\phi}{dx}k^2e^{\frac{\phi}{E_t}}=[E_tk^2e^{\frac{\phi}{E_t}}]'$$

Now Integrate!!!